# May I eat some of the stores food before I purchase it?

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing

There are times when I'm at the supermarket and I would like to drink one of the store's drinks **before** I purchase the drink. Or maybe I want to give my kids something in the store so that they stay calm while I do my shopping. I fully plan on purchasing whatever I eat/drink and I see that it's normal for other people to do this.

The question is: Is this permissible? And if not, is there any way I can do this? (e.g. ask an employee if I may start drinking the drink before I buy it? Maybe an individual employee does not have the right to grant me that right?)

Comment: I have often wondered how this is NOT theft.

Comment: I would advise against doing this anyways - what happens when you get up to the counter and realize you left your wallet at home?

Comment: @rosends Meshikha is Koneh Deorayta. You've cemented the transaction by taking the object, even if you still have to pay. Remember the store wants you to acquire the items in it. This isn't like taking someone's property against their will intending to pay them back. This is just finalizing the Kinyan earlier than usual.

Comment: @DoubleAA As noted by rosends, that's only where the *daas makneh* is as such. If an armed robber takes the merchandise before you check out, would you still pay?  If you change your mind about a product, can you put it back on the shelf? (The store owner would presumably rather have money than merchandise, which is why he has a store.)

Comment: @loew I think you mean daas koneh, and yes obviously you need that

Comment: @DoubleAA Nope. Daas makneh. Only kinyan geneva requires just daas koneh.

Comment: @Loewian But your examples are things the koneh would want to get out of? Obviously you need Daat Makneh as well, but that's not what you just argued for. (I don't get why so many people keep writing extensively here about how agreement to acquire and to give is needed. Duh!!! As if everyone didn't get that??)

Comment: @do I was making two points: 1. daas makneh is required and it's not entirely clear whether it already exists; 2. it doesn't seem to be even the assumption of the koneh that the kinyan has already been chal.

Comment: @Loewian I don't agree with 2 at all. If I start drinking something I would never put it back on the shelf. If an armed robber stole it I would be obligated to pay, though I could see how some people would dishonestly decide they wouldn't be caught and so not bring it up in the confusion/aftermath. You are of course right that 1 is less than perfectly clear in many cases.

Comment: @do My interpretation of your "You've cemented the transaction by *taking* the object" was, as in off the shelf. Hence my objections.

Comment: @Loewian What's "hence"? I don't understand what the shelf has to do with anything. Once you take with the appropriate intent to acquire then you can acquire it even before paying. That's why it wouldn't be stealing even though you haven't paid. That's all I was explaining since many people would think that a transaction can't take place before money is given.

Comment: @do I'm not clear when you are saying the meshicha occurred. I assumed you meant when it was removed from the store shelf. If at that original point the daas was not to acquire, when was the actual daas kinyan, and how do we know that there has already been daas makneh at that point in time?

Answer (score 3):

Good question as many are not aware of the Halacha. It depends on the owner's opinion. The source is Shulchan Aruch ([Yo"D 359](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%98_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%98)).

So, if it is supermarket policy that it is allowed, you can, **otherwise it is a Gzeila**. Furthermore the above is true for Goy & Jew owner alike.

However, for supermarkets many Achronim state that the Halacha is that if you raise the product in order to pay you Buy (Kinyan) it with a condition that you would not change your mind before actually paying, since it is fair to say that the supermarket owner agrees.

Comment: Where in Shulchan Aruch Yo"D 359 specifically is this case dealt with?

Comment: @DoubleAA - See "אסור לגזול או לעשוק אפילו כל שהוא, בין מישראל בין מעכו"ם. ואם הוא דבר דליכא מאן דקפיד ביה -- שרי" and not only it is Gzeila if the owner does not agree, even if you intend to pay more than the product's it is forbidden ("אסור לגזול אפילו ע"מ לשלם דבר יפה ממנו " there, mark 2).

Comment: Which Acharonim are you citing in your last paragraph? That's the only relevant bit here.

Comment: @DoubleAA - the Psak that after Kinyan by raising (Hagbaha) was made, if one changes his mind before he pays, then the Kinyan is cacnelled "Lemafre'a" can be found in the Netivois Mishpat (Rabbi Yaakov Lorberbaum).

Comment: Re the last par., I highly doubt this has practical applications, at least in the U.S. Most supermarket aisles are not actively monitored other than by cameras, perhaps, that are rarely live-monitored. Most store owners would suspect your stealing the item if they were watching you do that. I think you'd have to tell the owner you were going to buy it and verbally get his / her permission. I think this could also be a problem of *marit ayin*, as others may think the store allows free sampling. Esp. if you are "sampling" a loose product such as from a bin of corn chips. (Sanitary probs. too!)

Comment: except that picking up an item in a super market isn't a kinyan for paying for it later when there is an expectation you will pick up items in the store to examine them before deciding to purchase them and may change your mind before you get to the register.

Comment: @Dude - In Israel it is quite common that one would open the Chocho (שוקו) bag or a snack out of the bundle he just put in her cart, on the way to the cashier.

Comment: Ok but my point is if you pick something off of the shelf you have no obligation to pay for the item and can still put it back on the shelf

Comment: @Dude - it goes like this: when you pick something off the shelf you buy it at that instance via Hagbaha (הגבהה). The thing is that this is a conditional Kinyan, the condition being that you don't change you mind before paying, in which case it will turn out LeMafre'a (למפרע) that the Kinyan is revoked. The fact that you buy Kinyan Hagbaha is what saved the Chocho opener from din Gzeila (providing of course that he pays afterwards so that the Kinyan is not revoked...)